# Kotlin method with generic return type

Tags: java, api, kotlin, generics, api-design

I have a method that sits between a client and a server and it needs to return to the client `ResponseEntity<?>`, with `?` being a different class type based on the server's response. Is it possible to have a method with such a signature? If yes, could you please provide an example?

"Alternatively, it was recommended to me to use a generic json object but I dont see how that could work if the client is expecting an object of specific structure"

Comment: Are you looking for `ResponseEntity<*>`?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections